# USB Webcam in Android

Tags: android

Is it possible to plug in a USB Webcam to an Android tablet that has
USB host?

I tried and nothing happens. If I plug in a thumbdrive, the contents
can be viewed using File Manager, but nothing happens for USB Webcams,
could be due to lack of drivers?

Has anyone got it to work? How about the drivers?

Thanks In Advance,
Perumal

Comment: Since on Linux, a specific USB webcam requires a specific driver, it stands to reason it would be the same on (Linux) Android.

Comment: I don't have one around to test, but could you try pasting the last lines from 'dmesg' when you plug your camera in? On android sdk, run adb shell dmesg, or use one of the dmesg apps if your host and debug port is the same.

Comment: @Kheldar: 85% of webcams are USB Video Class - a rather common driver, thou I don't recall if it's built into android default kernels.

Comment: @qdot I guess I was rather unlucky with both of mine then. Also obviously, I'm not talking of integrated USB cameras like the ones in MacBooks and other laptops... Interesting information though :D

Comment: @qdot: The dmesg message is "usb 1-1: new high speed USB device using sw_hcd_host0 and address 3"

Answer (score 1):

I'm in a similar position as you and I'm curious if you've had any success.

Have you tried loading a custom ROM/kernel?  What tablet are you using?

Video of multiple webcams working:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fCN6VUyUl9o

and a direct link to the source page:
http://brain.cc.kogakuin.ac.jp/research/android.html

EDIT:

This should theoretically work:
Compile the kernel with these defined in your device defconfig file

```
CONFIG_VIDEO_DEV=y
CONFIG_VIDEO_V4L2_COMMON=y
CONFIG_VIDEO_MEDIA=y
CONFIG_USB_VIDEO_CLASS=y
CONFIG_V4L_USB_DRIVERS=y
CONFIG_USB_VIDEO_CLASS_INPUT_EVDEV=y
```

This will enable V4L at the kernel level.  At this point, if you set permission 666 to /dev/video0 in ueventd.tuna.rc. you can access the cameras with JNI, but if you want the camera to be integrated with Android by default, proceed to the next step.

Then, build Android with this patch applied to allow V4L2 cameras to work as standard android cameras (note, this patch is from eclair from what I can tell, and may not work properly with newer versions):
code.google.com/p/android-m912/downloads/detail?name=v4l2_camera_v2.patch

Flash the kernel and custom rom.

Comment: Nope, I had no success till now.But using custom ROM/kernel, it may be possible. But I am looking at standard tablets from manufacturers running on their official ROMs.